# return url asking for login details?

Tags: url, http

Hi I have the below URL the return argument at the end is successfully retuning the user to sf and to the opportunity but it is asking for login details each time

How can I stop this?

> http://lffdlaxfsmp01/produktie/eConEngineHtml.aspx?
>    environment=produktie&model=Quote&modelversion=1.0.0&language=default&type=1& configtype=configuration&CustOrProsp=C&Number=505-001675&Oppid=505-  000072&company=505&user=amann&backend=axapta&newconf=true&active=true&mobile=f alse&Type=Product Only&SalesTaker=Andrew Mannering&SalesResponsible=Nina  Bayes&ReturnUrl=http://test.salesforce.com/006S0000008pucF

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the HTTP:// in the url to HTTPS:// solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing **test** from "http://test.salesforce.com/006S0000008pucF" with the actual Org Instance like Ex - **cs3** or **na6**

Comment: Hi I had is as cs1.salesforce.com first and had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are youn setting your session?   I beleive each time you hit that URL, salesforce thinks you have to create a new session.    Hopefully, this can help you with creating and maintaining a longer sessions

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm